# Find the conditions for the cubic polynomial to always be increasing

Tags: calculus

Given: the general polynomial equation $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ and a note that says  "$a$" can not be zero.

The question asks under which conditions will the polynomial always be increasing.

Okay so I'm wondering if I'm thinking about this too simply and just assuming that when the coefficients are greater than zero?
I've taken the derivative $f ' (x)>0 $and just noted that when $a>0$ and $c>0$ (and if $x$ is negative than for $b$ to also be negative in order to guarantee a positive derivative)

Am I on track with this? Any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is equivalent to $f'(x) > 0$. Since $f(x)$ a cubic function, $f'(x)$ will be a quadratic of the form

$$Ax^2 + Bx + C = 0$$

where $A = 3a, B = 2b, C = c$

For this quadratic to be positive, you want it to go to $+\infty$ at both ends, so it's sufficient that $A > 0$. Furthermore, it must lie entirely above the $x$-axis, which means it has no real roots, so the second condition is $B^2 - 4AC < 0$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
it is necessary that $a>0$ (why?). Then, the increasing condition is equivalent 'the derivative never positive'. So, just write $b^2-4ac \le 0$.

Comment: It should be $<$ not $\le$ because $f'(x)$ can't be zero at any point. If $f'(x) \ge 0$ then $f(x)$ is non-decreasing, which isn't the same as increasing.

Comment: **No**. If a polynomial is increasing, it is strictly increasing. $x\to x^3$ **is** strictly increasing.

Comment: $x^3$ is non-decreasing. It's not increasing at $x=0$

Comment: @DylanDang what does 'increasing at $x=0$' even mean?

Comment: The derivative is zero at $x = 0$, which means the function is flat at the point, neither increasing nor decreasing.

Comment: The function is strictly increasing for $x<0$ and $x>0$ but not on the entire line

Comment: @DylanDang what I learnt when I was 9 is that strictly increasing is $\forall x,y \ \ \ x<y \implies f(x) < f(y)$. So, this is false. For which $x,y$, please?

Comment: What I learned was $f(x)$ is increasing if $f'(x) > 0$, decreasing if $f'(x) < 0$, and neither if $f'(x) = 0$

Comment: @DylanDang well, I still does not see an answer to my last question, just affirmations of strange concepts such as 'increasing at $x=0$'.

Comment: I'm just saying that I learned differently from you. I'm not saying which is right or wrong, because I don't know.

Comment: that is not the point. The point is that this is strictly increasing, even if there is a zero as long as it is isolated. If wrong, find a counterexample.

Comment: That was what I learned. $f(x)$ is increasing at $x=a$ if $f'(a) > 0$

Comment: I intepret "increasing" to mean increasing at all points, or $f'(x) > 0, \forall x$. So maybe we just understand the problem differently

Comment: let me say it again: ***increasing at a point does not make sense***.

Comment: Oh well. That was what I was taught.